# Image and kernal of the trace map for sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of rank $r\geq 1$ on a scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, then we have a evaluation map
$$ev:\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X$$
whose induced stalk maps are
$$ev_x:\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\mathcal{F}_x,\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\otimes\mathcal{F}_x\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{X,x},\quad (f,t)\mapsto f(t)$$
Does it mean that the morphism $ev$ is always surjective? If not whay would be the image of this morphism?

Also, I want to know how should I look at the kernel of this morphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this map is surjective (because the evaluation $\mathrm{Hom}(M,R) \otimes M \rightarrow R$ is surjective when $M$ is free of finite rank over $R$).

Another way to see this is that $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})$ (given by $\mu \otimes f \longmapsto (g \longmapsto \mu(g)f$) is an isomorphism, through which your evaluation map is the usual trace – the kernel corresponds to these (local) endomorphisms which have trace zero.